# Why are Iwahori subgroups compact?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-groups

I read the definition of Iwahori subgroup but I don't know why it is compact.
Does anyone know how to prove it?

Comment: Could you add the definition to the question?

Comment: It depends on the context: If the nonarchimedean valued field is locally compact, then Iwahori subgroups are compact, but not otherwise.

Comment: definition of Iwahori subgroup [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwahori_subgroup)

Comment: Your link contains two definitions: One is algebraic and the 2nd is in terms of the associated affine building. You should spell out the details in your post. Depending on the details, the proofs will be different. Further, you should say what you know about the question. For instance, if you use buildings, then explain if you already know that these are locally compact.